# Running cleanup when a react native app is closed

Tags: react-native

#### In my react-native app's code:

- I am monitoring AppState changes
- When AppState changes to 'inactive' or 'background', I write about 2000 key/value pairs of data to AsyncStorage
- When the app starts I read this data

#### When I test the app on android (didn't test on iOS yet):

- If I minimize the app, the data is written as expected. I can see that by closing the app after minimizing it, and restarting it
- However, if I click on the 'Recent' button in the navigation bar (which changes AppState to 'inactive') and immediately click on the 'X' button at the top right of the app, the data doesn't seem to be written, or at least not all of it (I am not checking all 2000 values, just few of them). If I try to write only few values, they are written

#### Question:

- The explanation to the above behavior seems to be simple: the app has enough time to perform few operations before I click on 'close', but not to write 2000 values. Is there a way to perform the writing before the app is closed?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's not recommended to do any async function or anything that could take too long. Because you don't have the control of how much time it will take to write the 2000 values. The app can go to background and the SO can kill the proccess of your app. When the app is in background is the SO that controls it.

Comment: OS* sorry. OS is the operational system. (Android  or iOS) In case of the mobile phones.

Comment: OS, never heard of it... :)
Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, not what I was looking for. Most likely, there is no way to do what I want to do...